# How can I know which chat generate "chat not found" excepcion on telegram bot?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I´m developing a telegram bot in c#. 
Using the class `TelegramBotClient` in `Telegram.Bot` library.

When I send a message with `SendTextMessageAsync` if the user had left the bot channel, I receive `Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ChatNotFoundException: 'chat not found'`.

Does anyone know if it´s possible to know which chat_id has throw the excepcion? Inner Exception is null.

If it´s not possible to know when I catch the exception. 
How can I know if someone has left bot channel?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the newest version of Telegram.Bot (15.0.0) and this information it´s not supported on it.

Anyway I have solved the problem creating an specific fork of this version.

And also I have sugested this improvement to Telegram.Bot developers.
You can see the solution here:

https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/issues/831

If you prefer I can comment here the solve.

Thanks!!!